# Flutter: How can I pass data back to Navigator when I use iOS swipe back gesture?

Tags: ios, flutter, navigator

How can I pass some data back to Navigator when I close the page with iOS swipe back gesture? If I close the page manually, obviously everything works correctly, because when I close it, I call the Navigator.pop() method and pass the data in the arguments. But how do I do this when I go back with swipe gesture?

P.S. WillPopScope will not help, only relevant for Android.

Comment: "WillPopScope will not help, only relevant for Android"—I don't think this is true. Why do you say that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to directly pass the result without using `Navigator.pop()`. I can think of two ways for solving the issue:

1. If swiping back means "Cancel" (as opposite to e.g. submitting data via some explicit button, where you can call `Navigator.pop(result)`), then you can distinguish these 2 cases by checking if result of `Navigator.push()` is not null.
2. You can use a shared state somewhere up the tree to store data using [one of the state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).