# Is there way to pass data when using a swipe back gesture in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

Does anyone know how to pass data when using a swipe back gesture in Flutter?
I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find a solution.

I tried using PopScope widget, but the thing is the method only gets called when the screen popped so, it doesn't help anything.

> PopScope(    onPopInvoked:(bool x){} )

Flutter version 3.16.0

Comment: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065790/flutter-how-can-i-pass-data-back-to-navigator-when-i-use-ios-swipe-back-gesture)

Comment: Yes, I've read this question. I expected to be a solution since the question was posted 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

in the leading property of appBar

```
leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Globals.isIOS ? Icons.arrow_back_ios_new : Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              print('userTasks.length: ' + userTasks.length.toString());
              Navigator.pop(context, userTasks.length);
            },
          ),
```

in body use:

```
body: PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          child: ...,
),
```

in this way you force user to click back button to go back, here you can pass your data.

that's it.

Comment: Disabling the back gesture is user-hostile. Replacing the leading button in the app bar is not necessary. But you are right to point out `canPop: false`.

Answer (score 0):

> the method only gets called when the screen popped so, it doesn't help anything.

This is not true if you specify `PopScope(canPop: false, ...)`, as @Ahmad points out. Then `onPopInvoked` will be called with its `didPop` arg set to false. At that point you can call `Navigator.of(context).pop(returnValue)`.

Then `onPopInvoked` will be called again with `didPop` set to true; to avoid double-popping you would return early in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return PopScope(
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {},
      canPop: false,   
      child: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(count.value);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(count.value);
              },
            ),
            title: const Text('SecondRoute'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: count,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return Text('${count.value}');
                },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Disable the default sliding gesture and add a custom sliding gesture so that values can be passed when clicking the button to return or sliding back.
it works!